# How can I count the number of spaces at the beginning of a line in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have lines with unusual numbers of spaces in front of them (i.e. indentation). How can I count them?

Example text:

```
This line is flush left
    this line is indented four spaces
     this line is indented five spaces
This line is also flush left
  this line is indented two spaces
```

Example output:

```
[0, 4, 5, 0, 2]
```

What's the best way of doing that in Python?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend regex if that was your thought. That finds text patterns, not counts occurrences.

Comment: @cricket_007 you can easily do it using regex.You can find length of the pattern found

Comment: One-liner using `map`: `map(lambda line: line.count(' ') - line.lstrip(' ').count(' '), str.split('\n'))`